# Time to hit ground after dropping object

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, newtonian-gravity, kinematics, free-fall

I have an object that is 9 meters above the surface of the earth, in vacuum.  If I drop it I'm trying to figure out how long it will take to reach the ground.  My teacher gave me the formula below, I'm not sure how to use it or what I need to solve for.

$$d=v_0 t+\frac12  at^2$$

Comment: Hello there, and welcome to the Physics Stack Exchange! Homework and "check my work" questions should **ask about a specific physics concept** and **show some effort** to work through the problem. We want our questions to be useful to the broader community, and to future users. Please read [this post](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/714) on asking homework questions and [this post](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6093) for "check my work" questions.

Answer (score 2):

The formula that you have been given is the formula for the distance $d$ that an object travels in time $t$ if it is moving with constant acceleration $a$.

In your problem $d$ is $9$ metres; $v_0$ is the initial speed of the object, which is $0$; and $a$ is the acceleration due to gravity, which is $9.8$ metres per second per second. You need to find the value of $t$.

Answer (score 1):

So, first, a little I'm going to use "g" instead of "a" to avoid confusion with another variable I'm going to use later on.

So the equation becomes:
1/2 * g * t^2 + v0 * t = d

g is the gravitational acceleration on Earth, approximately 9.81 meters per second per second (m/s^2)

t is the time elapsed since the object in question began moving.

d is the distance the object travelled in the direction of the force (in this case, gravity)

v0 is the initial downward velocity of the object.

Now, let's reverse the equation:

1/2 * g * t^2 + v0 * t = d

and then subtract d from both sides:

1/2 * g * t^2 + v0 * t - d = 0.

Now, this equation is a type of equation you may have learned in your algebra class. Hint: The left side of the equation is a second-degree polynomial.

If you guessed "Quadratic Equation," that's correct!

So we'll use the Quadratic Formula to solve for t. In this case, a = g/2. b = v0, and c = -d. So a = 9.81/2 = 4.91, b=0, and c=-9.

There are two mathematically valid solutions: t = 1.4 seconds, and t = -1.4 seconds.

Now, one of those values for t doesn't make sense in physics. Can you guess which one? Remember, you can't go backwards in time!

Comment: Greetings! Please see [this guidance](https://physics.stackexchange.com/editing-help#latex) about typesetting mathematics.

Comment: @rob: Thanks for linking to the guidelines. I'd like to make a suggestion to the Physics.SE team: Have buttons for inserting mathematical expressions in your GUI. So I could maybe type in 1/2 by typing 1, pressing the fraction button, and then typing 2.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! Changes to the editor are a complex, network-wide project; see [this meta post](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/13349/44126) and links therein for some recent developments.